# Using mciSendString: how can i return status of sound?

Tags: c, mcisendstring

I'm writing a simple program to play sound files. right now I’m using mciSendString to play sounds.

My problem is that I need to return the status mode of the file(playing,paused..)
and I don't know how can I return it with the "status" command.

How can I do something like this?

```
if(status==paused)
{
printf("paused");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[mciSendString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes a `HANDLE hwndCallback` as the last parameter, you can create a message only window that is passed in this parameter as the callback and will process the [MM_MCINOTIFY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages sent from the MCI. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/348501/Use-of-the-MCI-mciSendString-function-requiring-a) - someone was actually trying to achieve the same, the snippet together with the comments should be enough to make it work.